# Why Can Only The Godot Icon Glow When Using World Environment?

Tags: godot, godot4

I used World Environment to glow up specified things.

But if I set the World Environment's Environment's Glow's strength to 1, and just change the Self Modulate. The objects can't glow except the Godot Icon.

*The scene is totally empty with no scripts. The World Environment's Environment is set to default except the Glow Enable(True) and the Background Mode(Canvas).*

[The New Empty Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS7G1.png)

The objects at the left aren't changed.

The other objects'(at the right) Self Modulate have all been set to r=100 g=100 b=100 (Raw).

I changed the World Environment's Environment's Glow's strength. It worked. But it will also glow up unwanted objects too.